# Dependency Injection vs Abstract Factory - choosing the right pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, interface, abstract-factory

I'm developing tool that migrates issues from old to new issue tracking system. I have separated everything with interfaces, but I'm not sure what's the best way to glue it back together. I have 3 dependencies, that require runtime data:

- INewSystemClient - client to connect to new system
- IRetryStrategy - handles timeouts and retries
- IMigrationSettings

These 3 dependencies are dependencies of many others. I couldn't figure out other way to glue everything, than registering these 3 as singletons (via DI container). I also know, that singletons are considered a bad pattern, so I'm considering switching to abstract factory.

Example relationship which forced me to use singleton:

- Dependency1(INewSystemClient client, ...) // constructor for Dependency1
- Dependency2(INewSystemClient client, ...) // constructor for Dependency2

INewSystemClient requires runtime data like user, pw, host etc.

Should I switch to abstract factory and make factory create objects instead of DI container?

Comment: In my opinion, registering a single instance in a DI container is not that bad and not comparable to classic singletons. The smell from classic singletons comes from spreading tons of calls to static fields/methods across the codebase, rendering isolated tests, etc. impossible ( or at least very painful).

Comment: Sure, you still have to deal with concurrency/state issues in the shared instances

Comment: Sorry are you using actually using the [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) or are you just registering a single instance of you object. The pattern is considered 'bad' registration is not really bad as long as it is an [Immutable object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'm registering single instance (via Unity container). Unfortunatelly I believe it cannot be immutable, since user should be able to change connection settings (without restarting app).

Comment: @KrzysztofBłażełek Well the good thing about single instances is they  use memory only for one object and no garbage collection  is done so it can be good for performance. You can still read the settings at the point of consumption. And if you are using Unity I guess you are doing WPF ant that is not the same as writing a multi user Web Api where this can be a big danger. Not saying use single instance just thing about it from all [sides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx)

Comment: @FilipCordas Yes, It is a WPF application. You made me feel a little bit better about this solution, so I'll probably stick with this one. Also, what do you think about using abstract factory in this situation? I may consider using it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing terms just like a [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) (most say it's an anti-pattern now) is not the same as a singleton instance in your IOC, an [Abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) is not the same as a DI factory. What you need to think about is [scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647854.aspx) or when the object is created and disposed.

In your desktop app there can be multiple scopes in which you can register an object (On an App level or "a singleton", on a Module level, on a thread level, on a Page level...) This usually depends on the framework you are using (Prism, MvvmLight, caliburn.micro...) if you are building you own system you might want to look how some of the other frameworks did it.
I know Unity has a cool way of handling [factories](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/using-unitys-automatic-factories-to-lazy-load-expensive-dependencies) and [lazy](http://pwlodek.blogspot.rs/2010/05/lazy-and-ienumerable-support-comes-to.html) initializations.

Usually a singleton instance is best used for stuff that won't be accessed in multiple threads that will change some values. This is when you need to create locks and you can slow things down in a big way like blocking your UI thread. For example if you have an HttpClient that just call a single backend api that every one can use it would make sense to make it a singleton scope.

If for example you want to write to a database you might want to have a different EF context per page so the entity tracking doesn't happen on two page.

Comment: Yep, much more readable.

Comment: @halfer thanks for the edit still a bit new to the whole thing.

Comment: No worries. If you check out the help when the editor is open, you can see how to use Markdown formatting - it's much easier to work with than HTML.

Comment: @FilipCordas Thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 1):

> I have 3 dependencies, that require runtime data:

From your question it is unclear how those dependencies consume runtime data. If they require it during initialization, that's [a code smell](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99). If you are passing along that runtime data through method calls on already initialized (and immutable) classes, that's completely fine.

> I also know, that singletons are considered a bad pattern, so I'm considering switching to abstract factory.

Filip Cordas already touched this, but I like to repeat: You are confusing two things. When it comes to applying DI, the *Singleton Pattern* is a bad thing, but having a single instance of some class at runtime (a.k.a. the *Singleton Lifestyle*) is completely fine. Some (like me) prefer making *all* components to be registered with the *Singleton Lifestyle*, since this forces immutability and statelessness, which simplifies registration and prevents all kinds of common misconfigurations, such as [Captive Dependencies](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

> Should I switch to abstract factory and make factory create objects instead of DI container?

As explained [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100), Abstract Factories are typically not the right solution, and I consider them a code smell. They are typically used to build up application components using runtime data, but as stated earlier, application components should not require runtime data during construction.